# Repeated matching for capitalized last names with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match names in  book with European style names. The OCR did a mediocre job, so the fact that the last names are capitalized is important. However, there can by multiple last names such as Luc ASSELIN DE WILLIENCOURT or Marie-Sophie DUFAU-RICHET.

I came up with the following solution, but I am sure there is a better way and I am wondering if someone could do better...I broke the regex up over several lines for ease of reading...

```
names = regex.compile("[\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+
                     (?:[\p{Pd}][\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+ | )
                     (?:[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}'\p{Pd}]*)
                     (?: [\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}'\p{Pd}]*){0,5}", flag=regex.UNICODE)

ntest = ['Michèle DUBROCARD magistrate', ' Marie-Sara durur Marie-  Sara.Durur@justice.gouv.fr Tél. : 01 70 22 41 71', 
'Jean-Pierre KELCHE, général d\'armée','ÉriC LE CLERCQ DE LANNOY', 'ÉriC LE CLERCQ DE LANNOY, fucker',
 'Éric LE CLERCQ DE LANNOY shlaphead', "john smith proctologist", 'John smith     Proctolog', 'john smith, proctolog', "N...", "GHESTEM", "Bill linebreaker,"
"his honorable Baron VAN BULL and her hc Marie-Eunice DELAGARDE"]

for i in range(0, len(ntest)):
    print(regex.findall(names,ntest[i]))
```

This yields what I want it to, but it it is pretty ugly . Any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I understand why your regex is working, so my first suggestion would be to use the re.VERBOSE flag and document your regex a little ( http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE).

I don't know it's a copy-paste error, but when you're breaking up a regex over multiple lines you should use triple quotes.

Oh, and use raw strings (`r""" ... """`).

Comment: I had just made it unusable by breaking it up for readability and the raw strings was a copy paste erro. Thanks @thebjorn for the `regex.VERBOSE`. Any ideas about improving the code?  new version       `names = regex.compile(r"""[\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+(?:[\p{Pd}][\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+\ |\ )
      (?:[\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}'\p{Pd}]*)
      (?:\ [\p{Lu}][\p{Lu}'\p{Pd}]*){0,5}""", regex.VERBOSE)'

Comment: Here is an even more complete version that is tested and works well. It captures multiple last names. `   names = regex.compile(r""    [\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]{2,15}(?:[\p{Pd}]     [\p{Lu}][\p{Ll}]+\ |\ )
    (?:(?:[\p{Lu}])(?:'|[\p{Lu}]{2,3})(?:['\p{Pd}\p{Lu}]{0,10})|    (?:DE|DU|LE|LA))(?:(?:(?:\ [\p{Lu}])(?:'|[\p{Lu}]{2,3})(?:    ['\p{Pd}\p{Lu}]{0,10}))|(?:\ DE|\ DU|\ LE|\ LA)){0,5}""",     regex.VERBOSE | regex.UNICODE)`